# Custome Mapping in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array state that I am trying to map into a component where every third item goes into a prop.
the array contains the following:

```
players: [1, "Timmy", "H", 2, "Julie", "M"]
```

Here is how I am mapping it:

```
const myPlayers = this.state.players.map((id, first, last) =>
        <Player 
            key={id} 
            fName={first} 
            lName={last} 
        />
    )
```

basically,
the 0,3,6,9... items of the array are indexes
the 1,4,7,10... items of the array are the first name
the 2,5,8,11... items of the array are the last name

When I try to map it into the component as mentioned in the code snippet above, I get this result on my screen:

```
0 1TimmyH2JulieM
1 1TimmyH2JulieM
2 1TimmyH2JulieM
3 1TimmyH2JulieM
4 1TimmyH2JulieM
5 1TimmyH2JulieM
```

The result I am hoping to get is:

```
Timmy H
Julie M
```

Here is the code snippet of my Player Component for reference:

```
<TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>{props.fName} {props.lName}</Text>
        </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Any idea how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how map works. Map applies the function to every element of the array. You cannot group them. What I suggest you to do is to have a structure like this:
`players: [{id:1, firstName:"Timmy", lastName:"H"}, {id:2, firstName:"Julie", lastName:"M"}]`. This way your map will work, plus is much easier to deal with operations like push or remove and other programmer can easily understand your code.

If you still want to keep that structure you should use a for instead of map.